# does glTranslatef() exist in GL4?

Tags: opengl, jogl

I'm trying to use the glTranslatef() in JOGL, but I receive the "cannot find symbol" error when using the glTranslatef() in NetBeans. Does glTranslatef() exist in JOGL 2? Am I missing an import?

Here are my imports:

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL4;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.fixedfunc.GLMatrixFunc;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.*;
```

Here is the affected code:

```
@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    final GL4 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL4();

    // clears the window to black
    gl.glClear(GL4.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // draw the shape
    gl.glBindVertexArray(triangleVaoHandle[0]);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL4.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // the error is here, cannot find symbol glTranslatef(float, float, float)

    // ensure completed rendering is pushed onto the screen
    gl.glFlush();
}
```

Comment: [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) belongs to [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) fixed function pipeline and multiplies the current matrix of the fixed function matrix stack by a translation matrix. Nowadays the vertex transformation is done in the [Vertex Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader) and this function is useless.

Answer (score 1):

[glTranslate](https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/fixedfunc/GLMatrixFunc.html#glTranslatef(float,float,float)) is still available in the backward compatible context, use [GL4bc](https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GL4bc.html) instead of [GL4](https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GL4.html) if you really want to use the fixed pipeline.

There is nothing named "JOGL 4.0", please read [this article](https://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/Overview-OpenGL-Evolution-And-JOGL.html) to understand OpenGL and JOGL version numbers and more. The latest stable version in August 2020 is JOGL 2.3.2 and the latest release candidate is currently JOGL 2.4.0.

Please ask JOGL specific questions on [our official forum](https://forum.jogamp.org). StackOverflow is great for general OpenGL questions but not for questions about JogAmp as only a very few maintainers and contributors come here.

I advise you to look at our wiki too to find simple examples [using the fixed pipeline](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Rudimentary_standalone_example_using_the_fixed_pipeline_by_Julien_Gouesse) and [the programmable pipeline](https://jogamp.org/git/?p=jogl-demos.git;a=blob;f=src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score -1):

In jogl, [glTranslatef](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.5/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/fixedfunc/GLMatrixFunc.html#glTranslatef(float,%20float,%20float)) can be accessed through [GL2](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.5/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL2.html?is-external=true).
You can use [drawable.getGL().getGL2()](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.5/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GLBase.html#getGL2()) to get an instance of [GL2](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.5/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL2.html?is-external=true).

Comment: What more does it bring? GL4bc extends GL2. Your reply is confusing. Moreover, your link points to a terribly obsolete version of JOGL even in 2021.